# CUDA error: Launch exceeded timeout in cutCtxSynchronize()

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu, windows

I am trying to render my scene with my GPU (GTX 660ti) but it always fail with this error and crashes driver.

[image]

Rendering blender's BMW benchmark scene works just fine, there must be something wrong with my scene.

Here is the **[.blend](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q0ua0cy4rzml337/snehulak.blend?dl=0)** .

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/Windows/Hardware/ff570088%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: There is a solution here changing the registry: http://artificialflight.org/blog/2013/cycles-crash-cuda-tdr-error/